# Librería XenAPI - C#

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, virtualización, dll

En dos repos oficiales uno de XenServer y el otro de XCP-NG, están los fuentes para la librería de XenAPI, el problema esta en que hay que compilarlas, usan OCAML y OPAM.

Los repos son:

https://github.com/xapi-project/xen-api

https://github.com/xcp-ng/xen-api/tree/master

El tema es que estoy tratando de compilarlas con WSL (probé primero con Debian, y luego con Ubuntu), y por más que sigo el paso a paso no logro compilarlas, o por problemas de referencias de paquetes, o porque no puede hacer el make, o porque al hacer todos los pasos (cuando no tira error) no encuentra nada que compilar en el directorio o por problemas de versiones y compatibilidades con OCAML y OPAM. Previamente usé una VM con Debian para tratar de hacer la compilación, y lo mismo, errores varios.

El punto es que estoy tratando de conectarme desde C# a un nodo XCP-NG para ejecutar comandos, pero no tengo de donde sacar la librería, alguien puede aportarme algo de info?

Desde ya muchas gracias!